# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(key).ConvertTo error in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Below is my code. I try to convert below code from asp.net to asp.net core. But in asp.net core in last line ConvertTo is showing error because Get(key) does not have definition of ConvertTo. Don't know what is the problem.

I am unable to find any solution how can i write below code in asp.net core?

```
    public static T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        if (!Exists(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("No such key in the AppSettings: '{0}'", key));
        }
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get(key).ConvertTo<T>(new CultureInfo("en-US"));
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the value that fails to convert. And to what type you are trying to convert.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you carefully reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration) first. In .NET Core the way how we work with configuration is changed significantly ( different source using, mapping to POCO objects , etc).

In your case you may simply use ConfigurationBinder’s `GetValue<T>` extension method instead of implementing own method for value conversion:

> [IConfiguration.GetValue](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder/ConfigurationBinder.cs#L43) - extracts the value with the specified key
>   and converts it to type T.

Answer (score 0):

Configuration in .net Core is now built on top of POCO's or IOptions for the most part. You don't get individual keys but instead you build up settings classes. Previously you had to either build a CustomConfiguration class or you would prefix AppSettings to "group them". Not anymore! If you take the approach of using IOptions it works something like the following.

You have your appSettings.json look like the following :

```
{
  "myConfiguration": {
    "myProperty": true 
  }
}
```

You then make up a POCO that matches your configuration. Something like this :

```
public class MyConfiguration
{
    public bool MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your startup.cs you need to load your configuration into an options object. It will end up looking pretty similar to the following.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<MyConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("myConfiguration"));
    }
}
```

Then the DI is all set up to inject an IOptions objects. You would then inject it into a controller like so :

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly MyConfiguration _myConfiguration;

    public ValuesController(IOptions<MyConfiguration> myConfiguration)
    {
        _myConfiguration = myConfiguration.Value;
    }
}
```

There is other ways to do this that don't use the IOptions object and you only inject in the POCO to your controllers. Some people (including me) prefer this method. You can read more here : http://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2016/12/26/custom-configuration-sections-asp-net-core/

And of course the documentation link for the official docs are here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration